# How to simulate a simplified model of crosstalk effect in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, multiplexer, crosstalk

How can I make simple model and simulate the crosstalk between two adjacent channels of a multiplexed DAQ inputs? I observe that in its most exaggerated form, a nearly exact duplicate of one channel appears on an adjacent channel to which nothing is connected. I need to demonstrate in LTspice or any simulator that both sampling rate and the load impedance has effect on the crosstalk.

What I want to simulate that how the sampling rate and the load impedance effects the crosstalk on the other channel. Im a bit confused how I can model and see the coupling effect between channels.

Comment: I would start by just putting some impedance between the channels; a small capacitor, maybe a mutual inductance.

Comment: Crosstalk depends on coupling impedance/source impedance ratio for high Zload , which depends on cable lengths, gap and relative orientation for pF and uH. e.g. Ribbon wire 20nF/m 0.5uH/m

Answer (score 1):

consider this.

By the way, as the analog-mux switches from one source to another source, the new source **MUST** provide charge to erase the voltage
of the previous source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNqKZm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

by the way, I ignored ON_resistance of the FETs. Also ignored inductance of the IC package, of bondwires, of PCBtraces, of VDD bypass caps for the Multiplexor power (+5, +15, -15)

Sampling rate will not affect the crosstalk, unless your rate is so fast that the LOGIC gates that drive the analog-switches are not able to fully control the analog-switches state to fully on or to fully off. This likely will occur at some multiplexing rate well above 1MHz. Also depends on how clean **YOU** maintain the GND and the VDD of the IC; will you simulate that?
Place 10nanoHenry in each VDD connection.

Search around; I already provided a fully-detailed schematic for this type of question, months ago.

Comment: Here it says high sampling rate will boost crosstalk: "Even under this nearly ideal impedance situation, a high
sample rate can boost crosstalk by minimizing the
capacitive discharge time on the multiplexer's channels. In
effect, the capacitance has less time to bleed off its charge
before the analog-to-digital conversion takes place,
resulting in crosstalk where none existed before." Do you understand what they mean? (reference: https://www.dataforth.com/catalog/pdf/an116.pdf)

Comment: Are V1 and V2 sources coupled to channels? But where is the multiplexer here switching through the channels? NOT1  and NOT2 are for multiplexer switching? Can you yourself simulate this? I need something I can simulate and plot the crosstalk effect.

Comment: If one input is floating, there is no charge source available to change the charge on the output  10pF capacitor Cload.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the crosstalk. If you are talking about magnetic coupling, then you could use two inductors (that are the same inductance as the trace or wire, use saturn PCB toolkit to find inductances). Link them together with mutual coupling in spice.

If it's capacitive that is also estimable by using a few pf's between traces or in the case of two microstrips you could use a calculator  or this equation to find the capictance, then put a capacitance in between the nets in spice>

[image]
Source: https://www.ourpcb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Stray-capacitance1-300x179.jpg

Also remember that wires are superconducting in spice unless you put some parasitic resistance in and\or inductance. Most traces on PCB's are in the 100 to 10mΩ range and have nH of inductance.

Make sure you have cshunt enabled in spice with something like 1e-14 or 1e-13 to simulate an inner plane of a PCB.